# Limit and offset with Bookshelf.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, bookshelf.js

I am using the code below to fetch all results from a table:

```
Search.forge()
  .fetchAll()
  .then(function (collection) {
    res.json({error: false, data: collection.toJSON()});
  })
```

But I am going to need pagination and I thought I could do it with limit and offset, but so far I haven't found anything to provide me limit and offset options.

Is this even possible or do I have to build my query with Knex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far, there is no bookshelf.js solution for this. It can be easily achieved by using knex query builder.

Comment: That's how I am doing it right now:
`Search.query().limit(PAGINATION_LIMIT).offset(offset)
    .then(function (collection) {
      res.json({error: false, data: collection});
    })`

Comment: Here is a list of interesting suggestions of how people implemented pagination: https://github.com/tgriesser/bookshelf/issues/435

Answer (score 8):

Knex query builder should help, first you have to call `collection.query()` so that bookshelf tap into knex query builder

```
  Models.forge()
            .query(function(qb) {
                //qb is knex query builder, use knex function here 
                qb.offset(0).limit(10);
            })
            .fetchAll().then(function(result) {
                res.json(result.toJSON());
            })
```

so knex query builder function -> http://knexjs.org/#Builder are now available for free

Answer (score 3):

This is how you can use pagination with Bookshelf. Considering you have a Post model for example:

```
    Post.query(function (qb) {
            qb.orderBy('id', 'DESC');
            qb.limit(20);
    }).fetchAll()
      .then(function (collection) {

       })
```

**But note that all the where Clauses must appear before the limit and orderBy clauses.**

Answer (score 2):

As of 6/2018, while core Bookshelf.js still doesn't include built-in support for pagination, there's a [plugin to do exactly that](https://github.com/bookshelf/bookshelf/wiki/Plugin:-Pagination). It lets you express pagination either in a "page/pageSize" or "offset/limit" format depending on your needs, while [under the hood](http://bookshelfjs.org/docs/src_plugins_pagination.js.html) it appears to make use of knex's built-in offset and limit capabilities on queries. Code sample:

```
Search.forge()
  .fetchPage({ offset: 30, limit: 10 })
  .then(function (collection) {
    res.json({error: false, data: collection.toJSON()});
  })
```